# PhantomJS queryselector().textcontent returns nothing

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, getelementsbyclassname, selectors-api

I am trying to get a number from a webpage: https://www.svenskaspel.se/resultat/keno with phantomjs, but evaluate() returns nothing.

there are 20 numbers on the page like this:

```
<span class="result-ball-number ">28</span>
```

one of the numbers is "crowned" (two classes in span-tag)

```
<span class="result-ball-number result-ball-number-kungkeno">47</span>
```

In phantomjs I get an array/list of all numbers with:

```
list = document.querySelectorAll(".result-ball-number");
```

but getting the 'crowned' number fails whatever i try.

```
document.querySelector(".result-ball-number-kungkeno").textContent;
```

This works:

```
var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
    var list = [];
    ll = document.getElementsByClassName("result-ball-number");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
        list.push(ll[i].textContent);
    }
    return list;
});
```

This fails:

```
var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
    var tmp = document.querySelector(".result-ball-number-kungkeno").textContent;
    return tmp;
});
```

Is the problem the 'span'-tag with two classes?

In the firefox webinspector I get the number in several ways without issues,

```
document.querySelectorAll(".result-ball-number-kungkeno")[0].textContent
document.querySelector(".result-ball-number-kungkeno").textContent
```

or

```
k = document.getElementsByClassName("result-ball-number-kungkeno")
k[0].textContent
```

..gives me the number.

In PhantomJS, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I tried these, and they were helpful in many ways. Apparently my version was too outdated for this task, so an update solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wait a bit for scripts on the page to do their work:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "https://www.svenskaspel.se/resultat/keno";

page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 800 };

page.open(url, function(status) {

    page.render("just loaded.jpg");
    setTimeout(getKeno, 2500);

});

function getKeno()
{
    page.render("keno.jpg");
    var num=page.evaluate(function() {
        var k = document.querySelector(".result-ball-number-kungkeno").textContent;
        return k;
    });
    console.log(num);
    phantom.exit();
}
```

> 47

A very helpful practice when working with a headless browser is to make screenshots now and then. Also, when trying to get contents of an object first make sure there is one.

```
page.open(url, function(status) {

    page.render("just loaded.jpg");

    getKeno();

});

function getKeno()
{
    var numKeno = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelectorAll(".result-ball-number-kungkeno").length;
    });

    if(numKeno == 0)
    {
        console.log("waiting...");
        setTimeout(getKeno, 500);
    }
    else
    {
        page.render("keno.jpg");
        var num=page.evaluate(function() {
            var k = document.querySelector(".result-ball-number-kungkeno").textContent;
            return k;
        });
        console.log(num);
        phantom.exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, and also increased the timeout because of the transisitions during page load. Still the return is 'null'.
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector(".result-ball-number-kungkeno").textContent')

Comment: What do screenshots show? I wonder if the page is loaded at all. We should actually check `status` in `page.open` callback, if it's **success**.

Comment: The page loads, first screenshot does not have the numbers in it, I put a render() in the `if(){  ..waiting }` clause, that shot has all the numbers but lacking the 'crown'.   Execution gets stuck in numKeno == 0.

Comment: Interesting. What is you phantomjs version / operating system so I could try to reproduce?

Comment: I have Linux Mint 17.3 with version 1.9 of PhantomJS. I haven't used PhantomJS until two days ago. I have used the --ssl-protocol=any flag since it is a https-address. I sure would appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Tested on version 1.9.8 - the script indeed won't work, because the winning number is never assigned (no crown): [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/MDnFTvW.jpg) Probably happens because of errors on load: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Ky4I3hu.png). I'd suggest you try the latest PhantomJS version, my sample above works fine with 2.1.1.

Comment: I got the same results, I guess the page gets updated by some script after loading? Anyhow, thank you again, I sure have learnt some new things. The solution finally was slimerjs for this task.

Comment: Of course the page gets updated after load, that's why waiting is needed after page.open. But more important nuance is that scripts partially fail if old PhantomJS is used (solution: use latest version). SlimerJS is a nice alternative, but is not headless and a bit slower.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the slowness of it. I'll give a newer version of phantomjs a try.

Comment: So, installed latest version as suggested, and it worked! I just thought that what is in the Linux repositories would work fine.. Thanks for your time and guidance Vaviloff.